# Simple ruby syntax if statement. Is this possible?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, syntax

I'm really new to programming and would like to know if this is possible:

```
def lock(a,b,c,d)
if (a == 3 || a == 5 || a == 7 && b == 2 && c == 5 || c == 6 && d == 8 || d == 9 || d == 0)
  "unlocked"
else
  "locked"
end
```

If it isn't possible, why?

So when I pass in: `lock(3,1,1,1)` it should be locked.

Should I do this differently? Is there a better way?

Comment: Logical _and_ takes precedence over logical _or_ operators, so you need brackets. I would go with: `[3, 5, 7].include?(a) && [2].include?(b) && [5, 6].include?(c) && [0, 8, 9].include?(d)` for the better readability.

Comment: also, you need two `end`s. One for the `def`, and one for the `if`.

Comment: Certainly it's possible (what you are asking about). You just need to fix your condition. Remember (or learn) that `&&` is "stronger" than `||`, so `a || b && c` is `a || (b && c)`, not `(a || b) && c`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it bad to make such long conditions? @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `include?` to make it more readable:

```
if ([3,5,7].include?a and b == 2 and [5,6].include?c and [8,9,0].include?d)
```

Comment: Thank you... Is it .include?d or .include?(d)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to add bracket properly as per your logic. Like this,

```
((a == 3 || a == 5 || a == 7) && (b == 2) && (c == 5 || c == 6) && (d == 8 || d == 9 || d == 0))
```